# UIWebView Embed video callbacks are not working in iOS8?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, ios8

In my application I am loading some webpages embedded with Photos and Videos. Also I am using the following notifications to manage the player,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(embeddedVideoStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(embeddedVideoEnded:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

This is working fine in iOS7, but in iOS8 its not working. Any workarounds? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This is one option, I have found.. The problem is that is not Will is DID become hidden..

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(embeddedVideoStarted:)
                                                 name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
                                               object:self.view.window];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(embeddedVideoEnded:)
                                                 name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification
                                               object:self.view.window];
```

If, I find a fix for the second notification I will posted it.. :)

Comment: did you find a fix? DidBecomeHidden is too late for getting the orientation of the screen back...

Comment: you can get the orientation of the back.. you might wanna take a look a [this ->](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611646/ios7-ios8-allow-only-portrait-in-view-controller/26612748#26612748) or [here ->](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694955/properly-force-or-allow-landscape-mode-for-youtube-embedded-video-in-ios-8-witho) I hope it helps!

Comment: I implemented such a solution, but the problem is that the supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow is getting called before UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification. And than the screen behind the video is landscape. I need to somehow manually invoke UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification

Comment: yah, If I understand correct it's exactly how it should work.. please notice that this is only for when the video goes to fullscreen and not if you are playing the video inline.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, if you want just log the `request.URL.absoluteString` to identify which url you want to target.. or just post a question with some related code to see if I can help you better.

Comment: @christijk.. I have same issue.. I have a html5 embeded player but native player comes in between.

Have you found any solutions to close the native thing?