# IOS7/IOS8 Allow only portrait in view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am building an app for iPhone that will have only 1 landscape view, and so i want to block landscape for all other, i have tried this:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

But it stills rotates

Comment: why not just setting the app for only portrait mode and then whenever you need the landscape mode just allow landscape mode?

Comment: @NorthBlast I don't think you can do that. If you only enable portrait in the project then you don't get notified of the orientation changes at all.

Comment: I have done it several times.. :) and my project is set to portrait mode.. known as forcing landscape mode ;)

Comment: probably you need to create an own subset of your navigation controller class, I assume you are using a standard `UINavigationController`, so then you need to override that class's `–shouldAutorotate` and `–supportedInterfaceOrientations` methods especially in your subset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will suggest to just make your app for portrait mode and then whenever you need the landscape mode then allow landscape mode.

First, as previously suggested click on -> Project name -> General -> Deployment Info -> Only select Portrait for Device Orientation.

Second, in your `AppDelegate.h` add this property..

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL fullScreenVideoIsPlaying;
```

Then, on your `AppDelegate.m` I will add this function..

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    if (self.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying == YES) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

After doing this, in the view controller that you need landscape create a function or just add this code to your `viewWillAppear` method is depending how you want to accomplish this..

```
((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = YES;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

Then for setting back to portrait mode you do this..

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = NO;

[self supportedInterfaceOrientations];

[self shouldAutorotate:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

You might need these functions for iOS 8..

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I hope it helps.. :)

Comment: What if [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player]; ?

Answer (score -3):

Click project and select Orientation settings from there.

Comment: And what about the landscape View that i need?

Comment: Actually, it does provide an answer. That answer may not be correct, but it is an answer.