# How to make a specific view controller auto rotate enabled if the app is not allowed rotate in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

"Portrait" is the only supported interface orientation in app's info.plist and I can not change it;

But I need to auto rotate a specific view controller;

I can not find a way to do this easily, the only way I can find is to rotate every view, text and remake all constraints while receiving the device rotate notification, but I really do not want to this.

Is there any easier way to implement this?

Comment: Allow rotation for your app in general and prevent rotation for all other views except the one that you want to be able to rotate https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1890/_index.html

Comment: @Paulw11 This doesn't seem to work for me, as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778355/why-am-i-seeing-a-glitch-in-the-counter-rotation-animation Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Important Points:

- **`If you want Rotation in Single OR more Screens so you have to enable it for throughout the application`**.
- **`After enabling it from Target -> General -> Device Orientation you have to manage on specific view controller in which you want rotations.`**

For this you have to Do Following:

Check all the `Device Rotation` mask in your application. `Target -> General -> Device Orientation.`

`SubClass` you `Navigation Controller` and write below code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    //NSLog(@"%d",[[[self viewControllers] lastObject] shouldAutorotate]);

    return [[[self viewControllers] lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
   // NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[[[self viewControllers] lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations]);
    return  [[[self viewControllers] lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

Return YES in all View Controllers in which you want to Rotate and No in which you dont want to roatate.

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: @tuoxie Would be easy for me  you share your application's navigation hierarchy.

Comment: Actually I can not change "Device Orientation"... at least can not change it as easy as just check several box ^^, I just wanna to auto rotate some view controllers with only "Portrait" is checked in "Device Orientation"

Comment: No you cannot do this  using "Portrait" is checked in "Device Orientation"

Answer (score 1):

Try this method in `AppDelegate.m` call from particular view controller where you want to make rotation enable.

`self.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying` is bool set `YES` for that particular view controller to make rotation enable

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    if (self.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying == YES){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
    }else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
 }
```

Comment: In my code: Property 'fullScreenVideoIsPlaying' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'; Am I missing something?

Comment: that's just a property declared by me in <b>AppDelegate.h</b> you can modify it <code>@property (nonatomic) BOOL fullScreenVideoIsPlaying;</code>

Comment: It's working, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611646/ios7-ios8-allow-only-portrait-in-view-controller, answer in this url is smae and more specific

Answer (score 0):

Use this method in your controller which you want to rotate

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```